# Is there a way to add 2D guide lines to my view that help you align?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm wondering if there is a way to add lines like these in the view?

[1[image: ]]:
Having lines stay like this while working in 3D

Comment: u mean ruler or grid lines

Comment: @atek  I am not sure what they are called but i think grid lines move with your 3d model when you turn view, but I'm looking for lines that stay.

Comment: i want to know what ur trying to do? r u trying to snapping some object

Comment: @atek I am not working on anything but I was wondering if this feature excists and if not I'll try and find a way to make it myself. but I have no use for it yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Grease Pencil, and set the `Stroke Placement` to `View`, like this:
[image]

You can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to create orthogonal lines

Comment: I did not know about that Stoke Placement feature, nice.